# 画像選択ダイアログを表示させるため、 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show を実行するとエラー画面が出る。

Tags: vba, ms-office

Excel（Office365　ver2310）にて昨日まで普通に使用できていた、

画像選択を行うVBAを記載したファイルにて、急にエラーが出るようになりました。

試験的に新規にBookを作成、そこにボタンを1個配置し、

そのボタンに下記コードが書いて実施してみましたが、

下記のようなエラーが出ます。

Sub ボタン1_Click()

fname1 = Application.Dialogs(xlDialogInsertPicture).Show

End Sub

画像

過去にも同様の事象が起きており、解決したのですが

再度起きてしまいました。

[image: エラー画面]

過去は知らぬ間に直っていたのですが、

また、マイクロソフト側のバグになりますでしょうか？
https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E9%81%B8%E6%8A%9E%E3%83%80/d1da6957-7062-43ba-8ff5-c917e08b527e

Comment: 手元のExcel(Office365 ver2309)でも同様のエラーが発生しました。しかし検証のために何度か(10回以下)ボタンクリックを繰り返していると突然エラーが解消されて正常動作しました。それ以降はファイルを変えてもPCを再起動しても発生しなくなりました。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。本日、再度実施したところ、正常に動作することを確認いたしました。マイクロソフト側で修正が行われたのですかね？ご回答くださり、誠にありがとうございました。